# Python-selenium iframe switch does not seem to work

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am using the python bindings of selenium (python 2.7.12, selenium 3.8.0) in order to select an iframe from a webpage. But this does not seem to work. Here is an example code:

```
driver.get("http://jsfiddle.net/westonruter/6mSuK/")
print(driver.title)
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@name="result"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(elem)
print(driver.title)
```

I am using some test page in which an iframe is included. I try to change into this iframe and expect the second print out to be `HTTPS iframe test by westonruter` (**in order to verify that I switched to the correct iframe**), but I get the same output again:

```
HTTPS iframe test - JSFiddle
HTTPS iframe test - JSFiddle
```

What is going wrong here? Why does selenium not 'switch' to the selected iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch is working fine, but to get `title` value after switching to `iframe` you might need to do

```
title = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('title').get_attribute('textContent')
```

The output is `'HTTPS iframe test by westonruter'`

Comment: I actually do not want to get to the title. I just want to verify that I really switched the frame (so that `find_element` calls will work in that frame)...

Comment: But if you not switched then attempt to find any element will return you `NoSuchElementException`...

Comment: @Alex, title always return the parent window /browser title values only.

Comment: The same with `current_url`

Answer (score 0):

`driver.title()` will still return the Title of the browser.

Try `elem.get_attribute('name')` to get the frame name.
If `driver.switch_to_frame(elem)` did not return any Exception then it switched to the frame correctly.